# AD B2C Custom Policy - Enable automatic acceptance of terms and conditions

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

Our requirement is to change the default behavior of having an end user ***explicitly check*** the "Accept terms and conditions" in favor of an industry trend towards informing the user that by continuing the journey, he/she is agreeing to the terms of use and privacy policy.

So we would like to go from this kind of self asserted UI: [Current UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkeT1.png) to this UX content and functionality: [Required UX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbMFo.png)

Specifically, I'm looking at the following code within **TrustedFrameworkExtension.xml** on the **ClaimType** with an ID of "***extension_TermsOfServiceConsented***":

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_TermsOfServiceConsented">
 <DisplayName>Terms of Service Consented</DisplayName>
 <DataType>string</DataType>
 <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
   <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="tos_consented" />
   <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="tos_consented" />
   <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.[domain].com/identity/claims/tosconsented" />
 </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
 <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
 <Restriction>
   <Enumeration Text="Accept Terms and Conditions" Value="true" SelectByDefault="false" />
 </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

Instead of having a checkbox here, we would like an input claim that defaults to "true" when the user elects to continue. In order to facilitate this I presume we'd need some sort of hidden claim with the a default value set to true.

What is the best approach to take to implement this functionality? I've not been able to find an implementation for this online, or in the official documentation, and based on industry trends I would assume this is a common use case.

I've also asked this question [o Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/969427/ad-b2c-custom-policy-enable-automatic-acceptance-o.html), but so far have not received any sort of response from Microsoft. Anyone else run into this same use case and solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user continues, add a claims transformation to the user journey where you set "extension_TermsOfServiceConsented" to true.

If you want, then add the claim to the persisted claims when you write the user attributes.

So something like:

- Self-asserted TP - required UX with Continue button
- ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider calling OutputClaimsTransformation
- AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail or whatever write suits

Comment: Thanks for this advice and help! Sorry for the slow response. I'll give it a go and mark as answer when I get it to work. I've been a little delayed elsewhere for the moment. I assume I should then remove the original extension_TermsOfServiceConsented from the TrustedFrameworkExtensions.xml file?

Comment: Ended up solving this a little differently but I'm guessing that your method would work.